# Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, undefined-symbol

I am having trouble trying this project to iOS Simulator.

this is the screenshot of errors:

[image]

I have modified in Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only -> No

but nothing change...

I did not make this framework, but the person who did it, also sent me his Xcode's project where he says that everything works well.

I'm not noticing any difference between his and my project, and in fact if I try to start its project in the simulator encounter the same mistakes.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide output of this command: lipo -info <path to fat library>?

Comment: I would check your build phases/compile sources to make sure everything that should be compiled at run time is listed.

Comment: @JohnTracid terminal give me this error: can't map input file: ... (Invalid argument)

Comment: @Mike what should I check in build phases/compile sources? Each framework is in <Link Binary With Libraries>

Comment: How you execute lipo command? For example if I have MyFramework.framework I execute command like this: lipo -info MyFramework.framework/MyFramework.

Comment: @JohnTracid ok here: Architectures in the fat file: ... are: armv7 arm64 x86_64

Comment: @JohnTracid but I know that he use this framework on its simulator.. (i don't know what version of Xcode he has) how it is possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have i386 architecture in framework's fat library.

Comment: how do I see what kind of simulator I am using?

Comment: iPhone simulators below version 5 use i386 architecture.

Comment: It is iOS version not iPhone version. What device you selected as target?

Comment: i'm trying with iPhone 5 that should not use i386.. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the Build Phases of your project and check the Compile Sources in there. It should contain all your .m files. This might be the issue.

And also try to clean up the derived data of the project by going to Windows -> Projects, and select you project from the left pane and delete its derived data by clicking the delete button in the right pane of project details.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in Build Phases i do't have any files .m relative to that framework, but i don't know how to get this file because in header of framework i can see only file .h

Comment: Yep. The frameworks are never shipped with .m files. Because they contain the code. They are shipped with header files (.h) and a lib file (.a) perhaps. That is the binary and contains all the code which can't be viewed like normal .m files. So, what you should check here perhaps is that, in "Build Phases", under "Link Binary With Libraries" check if the framework is added in the list or that (.a) file that may be present in the framework. Also if there is any (.bundle) file, drag and drop it in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list in the project's "Build Phases". See if that helps.